# Sequelize .count() unable to return result

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying to return the number result, but I can't seem to do so.

If I replace `return c;` with  `return 1;`

I am able to retrieve the static value. How do I return the result correctly?

```
exports.count = function(user) {

    Project.count({ where: leader: user' }).then(c => {
        console.log("There are " + c + " projects with an id greater than 25.")

    })
    return c;
};
```

Comment: you are returning `c` outside the promise scope

Comment: and how do you intend to use exported `count`? Should it work as chainable promise like `Project.count`?

Comment: @kiddorails Basically I want to assign the function count's return result c to a variable in the main.js file

Comment: but the underlying function you are using is asynchronous and there is no guarantee when it will resolve. To handle it, I will suggest you to construct it to either accept a callback(using function) or return a promise(using `then`) so you can handle it from wherever it's invoked.

Answer (score 1):

You can not return `c` like your code.
I think you should `return Project.count({ your_query })`.
And you can use that `Promise` (I watch your code and think it is `Promise`) with `then`
Or you create `exports.count` is async function, you can return like your code.

It look like:

`my_module.js`:

```
exports.count = function(user) {

    return Project.count({ 'your_query' })
};
```

`any_file.js`:

```
let myModule = require('./your_module');
//define user
myModule .count(user)
    .then(c => {
        console.log("There are " + c + " projects with an id greater than 25.");
    });
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean.